# How to avoid 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df_original`:

```
     a     b
0    10    5
1    12    6
2    14    1
```

Now I want to make a new dataframe containing all rows where `c > 5`, and then set a new column value on this new dataframe:

```
df = df_original[df_original['b'] > 5]
df['c'] = df['a'] / df['b']
```

But I get a warning:

```
 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:25: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
 A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
 Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
 See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I'm quite happy if `c` doesn't make its way back to the original dataframe. But how should I do this properly and avoid warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html#pandas.DataFrame.copy) to avoid the warning:

```
In [118]:
df1 = df[df['b'] > 5].copy()
df1['c'] = df1['a'] / df1['b']
df1

Out[118]:
    a  b    c
1  12  6  2.0
```

This avoids the ambiguity in your call

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assign`, which assigns a new column to the dataframe and returns a new copy.  This was added in version 0.16.0:

```
>>> df.assign(c = df.a / df.b)
    a  b  c
1  12  6  2
```